# Viewing CSS comments in Internet Explorer's F12 Developer Tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging

I never noticed this before, but IE's dev tools completely strip out CSS comments in the CSS tab. I'm working with a large front-end framework and need to wade through the dev version of the CSS -- mainly to cross-reference the documentation/comments. Am I missing a setting/flag/whatever, or am I out of luck?

Comment: this really isn't a question for stack over flow i'm afraid.

Comment: You might want to try the IE11 preview release -- the dev tools have been completely overhauled for the new version and you may find that you get more joy with them. For the time being, using the IE11 preview will also mean using Windows 8.1 preview (you can run it in a VM if you don't want to install it for real), but I gather they do plan to release it for Windows 7 as well.

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. The CSS Tab's contents are derived from the CSS Object model, and comments aren't in that OM, hence they can't appear here. In the IE11 Preview, the CSS tab is gone but you can show the CSS in the "Debugger" tab and the comments are present there...

Comment: @JamieHutber I might be wrong, but I think I'm on topic since the question covers "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not ideal I would have to suggest using firebug lite.

https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

It will at least give you half decent tools to view these kind of things.